# NumPy vectorized function for different sized input arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am new to Numpy. I'm trying to write a data visualization program and I need to turn a grid of numbers into a grid of colors. It should be pretty obvious how I've tried to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pdb

colors = np.array(["red","blue","green","yellow"])
data = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3],(4,4))

def color_in_square(val, cmap):
    return cmap[val]

color_grid = np.vectorize(color_in_square)

display = color_grid(data,colors)

print(display)
```

That code fails as it is. It does work if I call colors from color_in_square() as a global variable, but the vectorize() function won't let me pass through differently sized arrays as inputs, which I need to for it to work with the rest of my module. What am I missing to be able to do that, or am I going about this all wrong? Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to vectorize an indexing operation?  Also can you provide an input that `colors[data]` *doesn't* work for?

Comment: Don't try to use `np.vectorize`.  If you must iterate, do so explicitly.

Comment: @user3483203 Because I'm trying to do the operation on every cell in data at once. How else do I do it, if not with vectorize? I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're getting at with the second part of your response.

Comment: For your input, using simply `colors[data]` works just fine.